# Looking for an XSLT to convert domino document rich text fields

Tags: xml, xslt, lotus-notes

I want to convert a domino rich text field to html by exporting the dxl and using an xslt convert the rich text to an html string.

Has anyone done anything like this before?  I hate to start from scratch as my xslt skills are sadly lacking.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at PD4ML. I believe their free converter includes a XSLT stylesheet.

http://pd4ml.com/command-line-dxl-to-pdf-converter.htm